# Determine the number of records in an OLEDB Recordset

Tags: powershell, csv, sql-query-store

I stole the following code that allows me to query a csv file with via a SQL query. The code reliably outputs a table which is nice. Ultimately what I would like to do is perform an action if the results of my query is zero records.

How would I go about doing that?

```
$firstRowColumnNames = "Yes"
$delimiter = ","

$provider = 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.16.0' 
$connstring = "Provider=$provider;Data Source=$(Split-Path $csv);Extended Properties='text;HDR=$firstRowColumnNames;';"
$tablename = (Split-Path $csv -leaf).Replace(".","#")
$sql = "SELECT * from [$tablename] Where sSamAccountName='acco'"
$sql
$conn = New-Object System.Data.OleDb.OleDbconnection
$conn.ConnectionString = $connstring
$conn.Open()
$cmd = New-Object System.Data.OleDB.OleDBCommand
$cmd.Connection = $conn
$cmd.CommandText = $sql
# Load into datatable
$dt = New-Object System.Data.DataTable
$dt.Load($cmd.ExecuteReader("CloseConnection"))
#Clean up
$cmd.dispose | Out-Null; $conn.dispose | Out-Null
#Output results
$dt | Format-Table -AutoSize
```

Comment: Check if your `$dt`'s `Rows.Count == 0`.

Comment: Ha!! Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

Following [Dai's helpful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70231002/determine-the-number-of-records-in-an-oledb-recordset#comment124149271_70231002) comment, on PowerShell syntax you can check this using the [`-not`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_logical_operators?view=powershell-7.2) logical operator as another alternative to `Rows.Count -eq 0`:

```
$dt = [System.Data.DataTable]::new()
$dt.Columns.AddRange(@('col1','col2'))
# DataTable only has 2 columns defined but now Rows

-not $dt.Rows.Count  # -not 0 or -not $null -> $true // [int]$null = 0
[bool]$dt.Rows.Count # [bool]$null or [bool]0 -> $false

# Add a new Row to the DataTable
$row = $dt.NewRow()
$row['col1'] = 'ExampleVal1'
$row['col2'] = 'ExampleVal2'
$dt.Rows.Add($row)

-not $dt.Rows.Count  # not 0 or not null when negated -> $false
[bool]$dt.Rows.Count # not 0 or not null in boolean expression -> $true

$dt.Dispose()
```